# Adding an application to com.apple.quarantine

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-catalina

I have removed the com.apple.quarantine attribute from an app using `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Application/appname.app` and now I want to add it back to the quarantine list because that was not the app I wanted to remove from the quarantine list.

I have tried using `xattr -w com.apple.quarantine /Application/appname.app` but on checking with `sudo xattr /applications/appname.app` it doesn't show that the attribute is added

Help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `xattr -w com.apple.quarantine /Application/appname.app` you need to provide a value for the `com.apple.quarantine` attribute.  It is not obvious what to use as the value!

I can't do better than point you to this Ask Different question and answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256625/how-to-set-restore-the-com-apple-quarantine-attribute which answers your question as well as adding more detail about `com.apple.quarantine`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is download a new copy, then (if successful) delete the previous copy.